# Kernel feature mapping: Derivation of polynomial kernel

Tags: kernel-trick, polynomial

The question is related to the derivation shown in section 3.1 Examples in the following lecture:
http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/281B-spring04/lectures/lec4.pdf

I am confused about the following equation:
$$\langle x,y \rangle = (x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+ ... + x_{m}y_{m})^{r}$$
Shouldn't the LHS be $(\langle x,y \rangle)^r$?

Also, it has the following description:

> When one distributes the product out, each term will be a combination of sum
>   $x_{i}y_{i}$ from each of $r$ factors.
>   This gives a sum of monomials each of the same degree, $r$. We can write it > as:
>   $$\langle x,y \rangle = x_{1}^{i_{1}} y_{1}^{i_{1}} x_{2}^{i_{2}} y_{2}^{i_{2}} ... x_{m}^{i_{m}} y_{m}^{i_{m}}  $$

I was unable to understand how the above equation follows from the given description.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that, as you said, it should be $\langle x, y \rangle^r = (x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_my_m )^r$, unless they use $\langle x, y \rangle$ for $K(x, y)$ which is not so common. For the second case, I think it should be

$$\sum_{i_1+ \cdots + i_m=r} \left(
\frac{r!}{i_1!\cdots i_m!}\right)  x_1^{i_1}y_1^{i_1} \cdots x_1^{i_m}y_1^{i_m}$$

by the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).